# Unable to launch slave in JMeter 4.0

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I want to do the JMeter Master Slave setup in JMeter 4.0 in Windows OS.
I have done the following change in the jmeter-server file.

RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.304.61.62

To launch the slave I execute the following command from the bin folder

jmeter-server

This is working in JMeter 3.1. But getting the following error in JMeter 4.0

```
ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred:
```

java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is: 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at 
    sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at 
    sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at 
    org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.startServer(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:501) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown 
    Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]

```
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:245) [ApacheJMeter.jar:4.0 r1823414]
```

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~
[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.loadStore(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:148) ~
[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:100) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 
r1823414]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Setting Up SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) chapter of the [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) JMeter User Manual entry you need to do one of the following things:

1. If you want to use secure communication between master and slaves you need to launch `create-rmi-keystore` script (it's located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) - it will produce the required `rmi_keystore.jks` file.
2. If you [don't want to use secure communication](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) between master and slaves you can add the next line to *user.properties* file

   ```
   server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
   ```

   JMeter restart will bre required to pick the property up

No matter of the approach you will have to implement either 1 or 2 on master and **all the slaves**

The above answer is based on [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker) article.